# Running for loops in SQL queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Suppose I had a table with the following structure:

`income event, frequency, user`

and sample data like:

`12,1,a
5,10,a
6,2,b`

What would a sql query look like that loops across users, and sums each income event x frequency

The output would look like:

`a, 62
b,12`

I am relatively new to sql so have little experience with group by functions, and am coming from an R background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT user, SUM([income event] * frequency) AS SumOfEvents FROM [tablename] GROUP BY user
```

When you `GROUP BY` a field, you are aggregating (e.g., `SUM`, `COUNT`) values for any of the other columns you `SELECT` by. You would just specify the columns you `GROUP` by.

So `user` would just be selected, then you'd take the `SUM` of the product of the other columns.